# Aspect ratio boxes slightly off in CSS Grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I wanted to make a grid of images using css grid, with all images being different sized squares.

I stumbled on the article on css tricks: [Aspect Ratios for Grid Items](https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratios-grid-items/)

On their [example on codepen](https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/POjJQG) I noticed that the square 1/1 ratio grid is always 4px higher than wide.

I can't figure out how to remove these 4px.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  place-items: start;
}
.grid > * {
  background: orange;
  width: 100%;
}
.grid > [style^='--aspect-ratio']::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1px;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: calc(100% / (var(--aspect-ratio)));
  vertical-align: bottom; /* new */
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div style="--aspect-ratio: 2/1;">2/1</div>
  <div style="--aspect-ratio: 3/1;">3/1</div>
  <div style="--aspect-ratio: 1/1;">1/1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The `::before` pseudo-element is set to `display: inline-block`. This activates baseline alignment, which breaks the 1:1 ratio. Add `vertical-align: bottom` to the pseudo-element.